# Android sqlite Creating new column from percentage of user data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to sqlite but I'm wondering if it would work for my app. I have 3 user inputted values. I'm wondering if it's possible to do this. I think the best way to explain is an example.

I have table with 3 columns. The first column values will be either "squat", "bench", or "deadlift". The second column will be a percentage, so 65% for example. The third column will be weight. This columns values will be a percentage of user inputted data. I have a edit text where the user inputs their squat, bench, and Deadlift weights.

I'm wondering if there's a way to take those values, multiply them by the percentage column, and input them into the weight column.

For example, say they input 150 for squat, and the value is stored in variable called squatVar. Is there a way to say "if column 1 = "squat" { squatVar * percent = columns weight}

I would need it to update every row though, as there will be many rows with "squat" in first column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, you want one column to be a computed result based on other columns.

This is what views (or just select statements) are for:

```
Create Table foo(activity, percent, deadlift);
Create View foo_vw as 
    select activity, percent, deadlift, percent*deadlift/100 as weight;
```

The other way to do it would be with triggers, but in the case presented they would have no big advantage.